# Arduino Compliing, Multiple definitions error with Marlin firmware for Ramps

Tags: arduino

I going to build my 3D printer. Because I'm not a really good programmer I want to use the [Marlin](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/1.0.2-1) firmware. I just download, do everything what is in the ReadMe file.
First I got some errors about Libraries folder, but after a program reinstall that is solved. But now I got a very long error text, what I simply cant understand, so thats why, I'm here. One of my friend said it is a linker error, but he don't know Arduino software.
Here is the error itself, I shortened for the character restrictions, but I hope this is enough:

```
    Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(char, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::print(int, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(int, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(long, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::print(unsigned long, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::print(unsigned char, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(unsigned char, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::print(unsigned int, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(unsigned int, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(unsigned long, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::printFloat(double, unsigned char)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::print(double, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MarlinSerial::println(double, int)'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\MarlinSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_25':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: multiple definition of `MSerial'
MarlinSerial.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/MarlinSerial.cpp:55: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o:(.bss.current_position+0x0): multiple definition of `current_position'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:(.bss.current_position+0x0): first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `homing_feedrate'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `active_extruder'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `add_homing'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `min_pos'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `max_pos'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `axis_known_position'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `serial_echopair_P(char const*, float)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `serial_echopair_P(char const*, double)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `serial_echopair_P(char const*, unsigned long)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `freeMemory'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `enquecommand(char const*)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `echomagic'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `enquecommand_P(char const*)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setup_killpin()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setup_homepin()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setup_photpin()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setup_powerhold()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `suicide()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `servo_init()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setup'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `code_value()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `code_value_long()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `code_seen(char)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `refresh_cmd_timeout()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `ClearToSend()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `FlushSerialRequestResend()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `get_coordinates()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `axis_relative_modes'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `get_arc_coordinates()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `clamp_to_software_endstops(float*)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `prepare_move()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `feedmultiply'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `prepare_arc_move(char)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `kill()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `errormagic'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `get_command()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `Stopped'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `manage_inactivity(bool)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `Stop()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `IsStopped()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `setTargetedHotend(int)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `calculate_volumetric_multiplier(float)'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `volumetric_enabled'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `calculate_volumetric_multipliers()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `filament_size'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `volumetric_multiplier'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `process_commands()'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `saved_feedmultiply'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `fanSpeed'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `stoptime'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `starttime'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `CooldownNoWait'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `target_direction'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `cancel_heatup'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `extruder_multiply'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `extrudemultiply'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `zprobe_zoffset'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\Marlin_main.cpp.o: In function `pgm_read_any':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: multiple definition of `loop'
Marlin_main.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/Marlin_main.cpp:1358: first defined here
Marlin\motion_control.cpp.o: In function `mc_arc(float*, float*, float*, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, float, float, unsigned char, unsigned char)':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/motion_control.cpp:30: multiple definition of `mc_arc(float*, float*, float*, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, float, float, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
motion_control.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/motion_control.cpp:30: first defined here
Marlin\planner.cpp.o: In function `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/planner.cpp:181: multiple definition of `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)'
planner.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/planner.cpp:181: first defined here
Marlin\planner.cpp.o: In function `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/planner.cpp:181: multiple definition of `planner_reverse_pass_kernel(block_t*, block_t*, block_t*)'
planner.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/planner.cpp:181: first defined here
Marlin\planner.cpp.o: In function `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/planner.cpp:181: multiple definition of `planner_reverse_pass()'
planner.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/planner.cpp:181: first defined here
Marlin\planner.cpp.o: In function `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)':
C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin/planner.cpp:181: multiple definition of `block_buffer_head'
planner.cpp.o:C:\Users\Sastas\AppData\Local\Temp\build1993739053522187544.tmp/planner.cpp:181: first defined here
Marlin\planner.cpp.o: In function `calculate_trapezoid_for_block(block_t*, float, float)':
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your error is the same as the one addressed [here](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/1602), so try doing the thing he says, specifically:

> delete the folder C:\Users\Sastas\Desktop\Arduino\libraries\Marlin

This is, I think, because you put marlin in the libraries folder and launched it from there. Move it to the sketch folder and it should work.